# XCode 8 compatibility with swift 2.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I'm getting tons of errors opening a project which was working under 7.3 in XCode 8 GM.

I want to keep my project swift 2.2 compatible and it should be able to work with xcode7.3 for the time being.

In XCode 8 GM I've set the flag

`Use Legacy Swift Language Version`

[image]

But still getting tons of errors from API's which have changed.

For example `NSURL.absoluteString` in XCode 7.3 defined as:

[image]

but in XCode 8 defined as an optional type:

[image]

I've tried changing the base SDK to ios9.3 but wasn't able to do it (also tried copying the SDK from xcode7.3 to xcode 8):

[image]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835397/use-swift-2-2-in-xcode-8

Comment: I added that. Its in the print screen above. Doesn't work