# Button with image ,image disappear for only ios10

Tags: ios, image, uibutton, swift2

We code with Swift 2.2, and make 2 buttons on the top navigation bar :
one on the left called `addFriend`, one on the right `setting`. On the page of setting I've added a back button.

We test with devices whose system are lower than iOS 10, they work fine, but with iOS 10, after tapping on the right button (`setting`) and then tap back button to go back to the view (which have left and right buttons ), images of the buttons (left and right) disappear, but they remain functional.

How can I make them appear ?

Comment: First You should update your code with swift 3 bcz IOS 10 support swift 3

Comment: @iParesh , yeah , I know , we will do that later, because we have not enough time to do it , is there any other stuff can make it work ?

Comment: Yes, You can use with xcode 8. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835397/use-swift-2-2-in-xcode-8