# Swift 2.3 does not support for xcode 8.3.2?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, alamofire

I had my project in swift 2.3, after updating the Xcode to latest version(8.3.2) it shows following error in my project.

“Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

even if i convert it will show lots of syntax errors. What can i do on this?

I don't wan't to convert my code to swift 3. But i want to work as it was?

Comment: xcode 8.3.2 do not have support for swift 2.3. The only solution is either migrate your project to swift 3.0 or use the older xcode (8.0 or earlier.)

Comment: No need to change the code only go to build setting and find out "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" and set it to Yes

Comment: Starting with Xcode 8.3, Swift 2.3 "legacy mode" is no longer supported. That is clearly stated in the Xcode release notes: *"Xcode 8.2 is the last release that will support Swift 2.3."*

Comment: @Bhupat Bheda In latest Xcode "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" can  not be found.

Comment: @AnushkaMadushan please have a look of this url http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/xcode/quick-tip-fix-use-legacy-swift-issue-in-xcode-8-beta-3/

Comment: @Bhupat Bheda i went to target and Build Setting and then searched in the search bar but it can not be found.

Comment: @AnushkaMadushan i think it's not possible you can review the documentation or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107179/xcode-8-3-cant-support-swift-2-3