# swift version 2.3 is not working with any Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

When I open project, it is showing conversion of swift if I do conversion then it is showing errors in available framework in pod. 
If I do "pod update" but still it is showing me lots of errors in project. 
Most errors related to Alamofire and Object mapper.

If I do not do conversions then it is showing below:

“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

```
target 'JaClassified' do

pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper'
pod 'ObjectMapper'
pod 'DKImagePickerController'
pod 'Kingfisher'
pod 'Auk'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
end

target 'JaClassifiedTests' do

end

target 'JaClassifiedUITests' do

end
```

Above is my pod file code I didn't specify versions so it will update to latest version. 
The current code written in Swift 2.3. I have tried it on Xcode 7.x but not working showing errors do pod updation but still getting same. 
Also in Xcode 8.x versions getting same. 
I have tried same code on different machines till now I have tried on 7 different Mac machines but not getting results or error free app.

Can any one help me

Comment: possibly duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107179/xcode-8-3-cant-support-swift-2-3). Check with the pod version if the developer have updated and still giving support to his pod.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am unable to do it in Xcode 7 too.